# Wordpress not storing uploaded files

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

this is really weird. I am uploading files through the admin interface within Wordpress 3.0.

**Wordpress recognizes the file type and attributes, but does not store it within wp-content/uploads successfully.**

Upon upload I am given a url that points to a file within wp-content/uploads, that does not exist.

---

**Are there any common gotchas? I have no clue what this could be caused by** :|

Thanks in advance, help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your uploads folder writable by PHP and does it exist? Although WordPress should indicate this, it is a common thing.

#### UPDATE

If the above does work, try setting WP_DEBUG to `true` in your wp_config.php and see if there are any errors.

Comment: checked writing permissions are all set to 777. Could it be a problem with ABSPATH?

Comment: Only if you modified it yourself. WP sets this dynamically by default. Check my update.

Comment: some random person changed the upload-folder within wp-admin Settings.............. :| thanks btw